# Unknown decoder 'libx264'

Tags: ffmpeg, libx264

I have `ffmpeg` with libx264 enabled from [BtbN](https://github.com/BtbN/FFmpeg-Builds/releases) for Windows 10. This is the command:

```
ffmpeg -f gdigrab -c:v libx264 -framerate 30 -i title="FiveM" -f flv rtmp://MYSITE.COM/stream/MYSECRETKEY
```

Unfortunately I get this output:

```
Unknown decoder 'libx264'
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Position of options is important:

```
ffmpeg [input options] -i input [output options] output
```

You are trying to apply `-c:v libx264` to the input, but you should apply it to the output:

```
ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 30 -i title="FiveM" -c:v libx264 -f flv rtmp://MYSITE.COM/stream/MYSECRETKEY
```

With some [suggested options](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/EncodingForStreamingSites) added:

```
ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 30 -i title="FiveM" -c:v libx264 -vf format=yuv420p -g 60 -b:v 3000k -maxrate 3000k -bufsize 6000k -f flv rtmp://MYSITE.COM/stream/MYSECRETKEY
```

Some services require audio, so you can add silent audio if needed:

```
ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 30 -i title="FiveM" -re -f lavfi -i anullsrc -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -vf format=yuv420p -g 60 -b:v 3000k -maxrate 3000k -bufsize 6000k -f flv rtmp://MYSITE.COM/stream/MYSECRETKEY
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir :-)

Comment: thanks for this real helpful ... why is -vf format=yuv420p applied to the output? sorry im such a noob

Comment: @danday74 For chroma subsampling that all players can handle. Otherwise libx264 will try to preserve color info but most players can't play advanced pixel formats.